# How to read matrix from stdin(console)?

Tags: python

I'm trying to read from stdin and the first line specify the dimension of matrix always square matrix

but my code reads only the first line

Example Input

```
  3
     0   2   3  
     2   4   1 
     3   1   4
```

My code

```
def read_matrix(formatted_string):
    list_of_lists = [list(map(int, row.split())) for row in formatted_string.split('\n')]

    return list_of_lists

x = input("enter the list of lists of numbers?")
print(read_matrix(x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only asking the number of rows but not the content of rows themselves. Following code shows how to generate the full matrix:

```
def read_matrix(count):
    list_of_lists = [list(map(int, input('Enter a row: ').split())) for _ in range(count)]

    return list_of_lists

x = input("enter the list of lists of numbers?")
print(read_matrix(int(x)))
```

It will first query the user the number of rows and pass that number to `read_matrix` which will ask the user to input every line.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input),

> The function then **reads a line** from input,
>   converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline)

Please, note **reads a line**. But here you are trying to read 4 lines with one call to `input`. You might want to run a loop to take this input.